# Can't get to GRUB bootloader

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to get to the recovery mode through the grub bootloader but cannot get in because I have a very fast m.2 and load too fast. Is there any command I can use to boot into recovery mode?

Comment: try holding the shift key at boot time